# Using YouTube Data API to upload video

Tags: c#, youtube

i am now using YouTube Data API to upload videos to YouTube, my question is how many videos can i upload to YouTube for one day? Is there any limits of upload video ?
Thank you.

Comment: Hi! I think you can find this information in the conditions of use defined as your opened your youtube account. this is not a programming question and may be closed here.

Answer (score 0):

Something about 30 000 videos per day.